# What testing framework for c# is the most similar to Junit 4?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, nunit, xunit

Mainly from feature-set standing point, as well as similarity of method names/working logic/verbosity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) is a port of JUnit to .Net.